# How to detect certain moving points in a video using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I have a video of moving hose in an experiment and I need to detect certain points in that hose and calculate the amplitude of their movements, I am using the code below and I am able to extract the required point using detectSURFFeatures, the function get many unnecessary points so I am using cuba = ref_pts.selectStrongest(5); to choose only five points, the problem is I can not get a function to put a bounding box about this 5 points and get their pixel values through the video, Kindly advice what functions can be used, thanks :)

```
clear;
clc;
% Image aquisition from Video and converting into gray scale
vidIn = VideoReader('ItaS.mp4');

%% Load reference image, and compute surf features

ref_img = read(vidIn, 1);
ref_img_gray = rgb2gray(ref_img);
ref_pts = detectSURFFeatures(ref_img_gray);
[ref_features,  ref_validPts] = extractFeatures(ref_img_gray,  ref_pts);

figure; imshow(ref_img);
hold on; plot(ref_pts.selectStrongest(5));
cuba = ref_pts.selectStrongest(5);
stats1 = round(cuba.Location);
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to find the bounding box which covers all the five points you selected: stats1 now contains (x, y) coordinates of the selected 5 points. Find min and max for x and y coordinates. min values of x and y gives you the starting point of the rectangle. Width and height of the bounding box is now the difference of max and min in y and x directions.
- If you want to extract the part of the original image inside the bounding box: just copy that part to another variable as you want. Consider the following example.

  img2 = img1(y:h, x:w, :)

Here, x and y are the x and y coordinates of the top left corner of the bounding box. w and h are the width and height of the bounding box.

Comment: What I need is to put a separate bounding box around each point in order to track them through the video frames

Comment: You can access (x,y) coordinates of the each point. Then as an example, let's say the width and height of the bounding box you need is w and h. You can then access content around that point from the first image as, img2 = img1(y-h/2:y+h/2, x-w/2:x+w/2).